# FlatList, Load in from behind, Fade Effect

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

Kinda a unique question, I have a FlatList component that renders a bunch of images.. essentially like a slideshow.

I am trying to create the effect that the Pictures appear from behind one another, I was thinking of doing this as sliding one row right behind another, and then setting the opacity to 0, to create kinda a fade effect

Where as right now it is just like scrolling down a list with the flatlist

is this possible?